# WSO2 store API where in database the API parameters passed to each API call in headers are stored

Tags: database, api, parameters, wso2

WSO2 store API where in database the API parameters passed to each API call in headers are stored?
I can find the database for API here, but not the parameters: 
/opt/wso2am-2.1.0/repository/database
AM_API 
AM_API_URL_MAPPING
AM_APPLICATION_REGISTRATION

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

if you have defined the API parameters, you can check it via the swagger file. These swagger files are stored in the Registry DB under the REG_CONTENT table.

Comment: Hi Chandana,
thanks for your answer. Do you have any idea how records in REG_CONTENT
table are linked to APIs (table AM_API_URL_MAPPING or other)?